# How to CREATE PROCEDURE in H2

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2, h2

This seems to be a duplicate of the other question with the same title, but it actually isn't.

We have our business logic implemented mostly as DB2 stored procedures (I see that H2 has a DB2-compatibility mode - nice!).

How can we use H2 for in-memory unit testing with these procedures?

Unfortunately H2 seems to lack the CREATE PROCEDURE command from its [grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html).

I don't want to use Java functions as [stored procedures](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions). It would be best if the very same sql files could be used for testing and production as well... am I asking too much?

EDIT: we also use SQL cursors... again, no sign of support :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the compatibility mode doesn't go as far as supporting SQL prodecures. Currently, the only solution is to use Java functions. SQL cursors are also not supported, sorry. But I will add these feature requests to the roadmap. Patches are welcome of course :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response, honestly, I expected something from IBM in this department, so don't feel too bad about it ;-)