# Stored Procedure in H2 Database

Tags: java, stored-procedures, h2

I am new to database and recently started writing test cases for H2 database.
I want to know how to test a stored procedure in Eclipse. I have seen the following:

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

[How to CREATE PROCEDURE in H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955521/how-to-create-procedure-in-h2)

The sample code given in the h2database link,

```
"CREATE ALIAS NEXT_PRIME AS $$
String nextPrime(String value) {
    return new BigInteger(value).nextProbablePrime().toString();
}
$$;
"
```

- Where should this be declared?and how to run it?

PS - I have the H2 JAR file and am testing it.

If someone can tell me how to write a simple stored procedure in Java for H2, it would be of great help.

Also is there any equivalent of the following in H2?

"begin dbms_output" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? The statement you posted is a SQL statement, you need to execute it using the JDBC API.

Comment: I want to know how to call this using the API.Any sample code reference would be of great help.Where should this SQL portion be declared? I understand that this is probably very elementary but I am just starting out.Thanks

Comment: I think my Bounty of 200 points has been wasted because realized that H2 actually doesn't support Stored Procedures nor Derby does. These support Funtions and functions are not for insert/update/delete purposes. As can be seen in this function and Stored Procedure comparision. http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines :(

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow: I've expanded my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11840327/230513).

Answer (score 14):

**There is no stored procedure and sql userdefined function in H2 database instead of that we use java methods and create a alias to refer that.We can call that methods using alias.**

Below is a simple example:**

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS MYFUNCTION;
CREATE ALIAS MYFUNCTION AS $$
String getTableContent(java.sql.Connection con) throws Exception {
    String resultValue=null;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(
    " SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME");
       while(rs.next())
       {
        resultValue=rs.getString(1);
       }
    return resultValue;
}
$$;
```

Comment: I think you forgot `rs.next()`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Does H2 still not support Stored Procedures? Please look at my last comment in the questions comment section. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow H2 always supported stored procedures... Maybe your definition of stored procedure is not the same as my definition? What is your definition? Something that is 100% compatible with Oracle? Yes, H2 is not 100% compatible with Oracle.

Comment: Related examples are shown in [*SQL Grammar: CREATE ALIAS*](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias).

Answer (score 12):

You may have overlooked the examples in `src/test/org/h2/samples/Function.java`. Here's a related example:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("CREATE ALIAS getVersion FOR \"org.h2.engine.Constants.getVersion\"");
ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("CALL getVersion()");
if (rs.next()) System.out.println("Version: " + rs.getString(1));
```

Console: `Version: 1.4.191`

Addendum: The feature is not limited to functions; aliased methods can execute arbitrary [Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17295917/230513). For example, the `query()` method defined in [`Function.java`](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/Function.java) may be aliased and called as shown below:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("CREATE ALIAS query FOR \"cli.Function.query\"");
rs = st.executeQuery("CALL query('SELECT NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS')");
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("User: " + rs.getString(1));
}
```

Console: `User: SA`

Note that `cli.Function.query` is a copy of `org.h2.samples.Function.query`.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod (+1) - *finally*, a complete-ish example of invoking the Java function as an alias.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the way we used to implemented in our project. It might be helpful :)

```
package com.procedures;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CRITICAL_ACTIONS {

    public static final int SAVE_ACTION(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            return statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.CRITICAL_ACTIONS(COLLEAGUE_ID,JOURNEY_ID,TYPE,PRODUCT,DESCRIPTION,META_DATA,STATUS) values('12345',11111111,'ABC','Lloyds','hellow','hello','START')");
        } finally {
            //connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static final ResultSet FETCH_ACTION(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            return statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SCHEMA1.CRITICAL_ACTIONS");
        }finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }


}
```

Calling H2 Java Stored-procedure in Java :-

```
    jdbcTemplate.update("CREATE ALIAS SAVE_ACTION FOR \"com.procedures.CRITICAL_ACTIONS.SAVE_ACTION\"");
    jdbcTemplate.update("CREATE ALIAS FETCH_ACTION FOR \"com.procedures.CRITICAL_ACTIONS.FETCH_ACTION\"");

    jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createStatement().execute("call SAVE_ACTION()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure in H2 database is same as java methods.So write java methods and can invoke using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The `H2` is not supporting stored procedures. In place of stored procedure we can create a function which returns an output like  a stored-procedures. Same as we're using in registerInOut parameters.
For example, if your QueryConst looks like this:

`public static final String INSERT_EMPLOYEE = "{call INSERT_EMPLOYEE(?,?,?)}";`

then,

We can use `schema.sql`(which executes before `@Test`)

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS INSERT_EMPLOYEE;
CREATE ALIAS INSERT_EMPLOYEE FOR "com.test.EmployeeDaoImplTest.updateEmpStoredproc";

package com.test;
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:configxmltest.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Sql(scripts = { "classpath:schema.sql" }, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
public class EmployeeDaoImplTest {
    
    public static final String INSERT_EMPLOYEE = "{call INSERT_EMPLOYEE(?,?,?)}";


    @Autowired
    EmployeeDaoImpl employeeDaoTest;
```

and other dependencies....(if any)

```
    @Test
    public void testUpdateEmployee() {
        ..ur logic if any input data settings
        assertEquals("Inserted Successfully", employeeDaoTest.updateEmployee(input, INSERT_EMPLOYEE));
    }

    public static ResultSet updateEmpStoredproc(String name, String w, Integer i) throws SQLException {
        SimpleResultSet rs = new SimpleResultSet();
        rs.addColumn("input", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
        rs.addColumn("error", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
        rs.addColumn("count", Types.INTEGER, 10, 0);
        rs.addRow(0, "Inserted Successfully");
        rs.addRow(1, 10);
        return rs;
    }
  }
```