# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement " ? = CALL PKG_DATA_INGESTION.F_GET_CONFIGURATION_COMPONENTS([*]?, ?) ";

Tags: java, h2

I have created an alias for the package name :

```sql
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS PKG_DATA_INGESTION.F_GET_CONFIGURATION_COMPONENTS FOR
"com.db.aminet.cucumbertests.Orchestrator.H2databaseProc.selectComponentsConfig";
```

The java class for the given package :

```java
public class H2databaseProc {

    public static ResultSet selectComponentsConfig(final String componentConfig, final Date executionDate) throws SQLException {
        String h2Pwd=EncrypterFactory.getEncrypter().decrypt("ENC(bZO5WqcDhckxAFZhcZD5+6g3vbMMOZuwTHmtNKuIhBe4+oFdaDwintZvbNqDQYGj)");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", h2Pwd);
        PreparedStatement controlComponent = conn.prepareStatement("select PROPERTY_KEY, PROPERTY_VALUE from component_config where COMPONENT_ID = ? and INIT_DATE <= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and (END_DATE is NULL OR END_DATE >= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and IS_LIST = 0; ");
        controlComponent.setString(1, componentConfig);
        controlComponent.setDate(2, executionDate);
        ResultSet rs = controlComponent.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    }
}
```

calling the package in java :

```java
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.jdbcUrlDB, this.usernameDB, this.passwordDB);
            cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call PKG_DATA_INGESTION.F_GET_CONFIGURATION_COMPONENTS(?, ?)}");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, -10);
            cstmt.setString(2, this.componentID);
            cstmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(this.date.getTime()));
            cstmt.execute();
```

Error I am getting :

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement " ? = CALL PKG_DATA_INGESTION.F_GET_CONFIGURATION_COMPONENTS([*]?, ?)  "; SQL statement:
 ? = call PKG_DATA_INGESTION.F_GET_CONFIGURATION_COMPONENTS(?, ?)  [42000-176]

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking the stored procedure correctly? I am not an expert for H2, but should the call just be `call <function>`?
Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718865/stored-procedure-in-h2-database
Seems the connection can be passed into the store procedure method.

Comment: Here's another complete, complex example: https://medium.com/@callkalpa/user-defined-functions-and-stored-procedures-with-h2-database-a1cbfa510559